# Use script to send string through socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am using a program written in Python which accepts an input from user though socket (I an not providing the code here in order not to confuse, since it runs fine with passing a String like: `Hello world`). Though what i want is to pass a big String through socket using python like:

```
 $(python -c 'print "A" * 8000')
```

and the server to read 8000 times the letter 'A' not the above String as input. How is this possible?

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define KEYFILESIZE 41
#define BUFF_SIZE 0X1000
#define PORTNO    12345

void firstFunc(int FD){ 
  char buf[BUFF_SIZE];
  int cookie=*(int*)(buf+0x1000);
  printf("cookie: %x\n",cookie); //the server operator gets this info
  read(FD,buf,BUFF_SIZE*2); //overflow the buffer 2x
  return;
}

int servlet(int fd){
  char greetings[BUFF_SIZE];
  sprintf(greetings,"Greetings client #%d\n",fd);
  write(fd,greetings,strlen(greetings));
  firstFunc(fd);
  char* sorry="Sorry";
  write(fd,sorry,strlen(sorry));
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
  socklen_t clilen;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

  /*  if (argc < 2) { */
  /*   fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n"); */
  /*   exit(1); */
  /* } */

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0){
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  //  portno = atoi(argv[1]);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNO);
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
       sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
   perror("ERROR on binding");
   exit(1);
  }
  listen(sockfd,5);
  clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
  while (1) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0){
      perror("ERROR on accept");
      exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
      perror("ERROR on fork");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)  {
      close(sockfd);
      servlet(newsockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
    //make sure to wait at some point to avoid zombies
    else close(newsockfd);
    waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
  }
  close(sockfd);
  return 0; 
}
```

Ok so the above is the code of the server running in an Ubuntu vm. With netcat i connect to the server from another vm (running Kali) and i have tried to send as input: 
1. `$(python -c 'print "A" * 8000')`

2. `(python -c 'print "A" * 8000')`

3.`python -c 'print "A" * 8000'`

None of the above worked. Below is a picture of what the server sees after each of the above 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwrC9.png)

Of course what i wanted it to see in each case is 8000 'A' (AAAAAAAAAAAA....)

Comment: So... what went wrong? What is the question?

Comment: Confuse us with what you tried, without it its hard to help or even see the problem.

Comment: @timgeb Please see the edit of my question

Comment: @Memnon Please see the edit of my question

Comment: As far as I understood your question: You have a server code running fine and you can connect to the server via netcat. After the successful connection you enter a text like `$(python -c 'print "A" * 8000')` and its getting printed as same on the server console(As I see in the screenshot)? I think this is fine, this is exactly what your code is supposed to do. Or are you expecting it to do something different?

Comment: Are you expecting the server to accept the text entered from the netcat to execute hem as python statements. In that case this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987077/python-sending-command-over-a-socket

Comment: @pss What i intend to do is to send the python command as it says in the above question you mentioned as plain text and the server interpret it as command and print the 8000 (in the current example 'A') in `printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is to write a file in python which after the connection has been established (that is the part which i have done manually above with netcat ) will print the number of 'A' or any any string required. Example:

```
import socket
from struct import pack
host='ip_to_connect_to'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port_to_connect_to))
answer=s.recv(1024)
print answer
padding=800 * "A"

s.send(padding)
```