# send inter key in socket programing python

Tags: python, sockets, command

I have just started socket programming in Python. The code I have written is connected to the console of the program that is waiting in server mode and the desired command is sent to the server and is typed in the command line of the desired server and for The execution only needs an enter at the end, and my problem is how to include the enter key in the message  that sent to the server, considering that I do not know the server program and there is only one console at hand, which is according to the TCP/IP standard and in the form of CLIENT/ SERVER has the ability to receive commands. I will be very grateful for your help, friends.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
port = 6001
ip = '129.1.1.185'      #server ip
s.connect((ip, port))
command='DEX -W 52/34'  #The command to be sent 
s.send(command.encode())
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4987077/8353711) answer your question?